# selecting certain elements from a row and calculating mean of these elements

Tags: r

I have a matrix. I want to select certain elements from every row of the matrix and calculate mean of that elements. See reproducible example.I have tried following code suggested by an expert. But it does not work

```
test_data<-as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(4,-8,6,-3),b=c(-2,3,4,-2),c=c(2,-5,8,1),d=c(2,4,3,1)))
Rank<-apply(-test_data,1,rank)
top_n<-c(2,3,2,3)
result_output<-c(3,0.667,7,0)
sapply(seq_along(top_n), function(x) mean(tail(sort(test_data[1, ]), top_n[x])))
```

Comment: How do you get calculate mean, can you explain ? How is result 3 for row 1 ?

Comment: Sorry the answer to your previous question should be `sapply(seq_along(top_n), function(x) mean(tail(sort(test_data[x, ]), top_n[x])))` I had a typo there, I have corrected it.

Comment: @RonakShah Sir, That function extract top 2 from first row like (4,2). Then mean of these two will be 3. Similar in third row top 2 elements will be 8 and 6 and their mean will be 7.